# Why? Executable size cuts dramatically after changing build structure

Tags: c++, build, code-size

I am on my personal C++ project that builds a simple compiler, called [simplecc](https://github.com/cgsdfc/simplecc). Today, I triggered a refactor on it, which changed the way the main executable is built, or as I termed it, the build structure and the executable code size drops nearly a half.

My project has many components, such as   the `AST` and `CodeGen`, which are named after their functionalities. Each component resides in its own folder (both headers and cpp's do). There is a `lib/` directory that holds directories for all other components and a `CMakeList.txt` in `lib/` generates a single executable `simplecc`. **Now here is the difference.**

The old code:

```
# All source code is listed and directly built into the executable.
add_executable(simplecc
        Lex/Tokenize.cpp
        Lex/TokenInfo.cpp

        Parse/Grammar.cpp
        Parse/ASTBuilder.cpp
        Parse/Parser.cpp
        Parse/Node.cpp
        Parse/Parse.cpp
        Parse/ParseTreePrinter.cpp

        # More to come...
)
```

The new code:

```
# lib/CMakeLists.txt
add_subdirectory(Lex)
add_subdirectory(Parse)
# More to come...

# Add main executable.
add_executable(simplecc Driver/main.cpp)

# Link to all components.
target_link_libraries(simplecc Driver)
# More to come.


# lib/Parse/CMakeLists.txt
add_library(Parse STATIC
        ASTBuilder.cpp
        Grammar.cpp
        Node.cpp
        Parse.cpp
        Parser.cpp
        ParseTreePrinter.cpp)

target_link_libraries(Parse Lex AST)
```

and within each sub-directory, a static library (archive) is built from the source of that component. Finally these archives are linked into the executable.

While I think I just organized the code so that it is better tracked by `cmake`, it **cut** the code size of the executable dramatically! The old code is 14M and 3.7M after stripped. The new code is 2.4M before stripped 5.6M and 560K after stripped. How can this happen? It is generally true? It is project-specific? My project makes use of [CRTP](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CRTP) extensively.

**Edit**: these data is derived from a Debug build. I haven't done a Release build (will be added later).

Comment: Are these sizes for release (optimized) build? I would not expect something with "simple" in the name produce 14 mb executable

Comment: @VTT No, it is for debug.

Comment: Don't get your hopes up until you actually run the executable.  Make sure your build actually works correctly.

Comment: Sorry folks! As I saw @PaulMcKenzie's comment I run the program and it does not respond to some switches. It turns out some macro definitions get defined after the point it should be used. As the result the main() don't use some components so they are no linked in. False positive. When I fixed this the code size gained back to 12M.

Answer (score 0):

The code size shrinks because some components are mistakenly omitted from `main()` and not linked in. No magic or secret. Don't try to figure out any more.